# Can you use AirPlay to show an extended desktop?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, airplay

I just installed Mountain Lion and it has the new AirPlay Mirroring feature. Is there an option to extend the desktop, as you would with a second monitor, instead of mirroring?

Comment: Mac OS X Mavericks now supports this feature out of the box.

Comment: @Fabien - Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

I've seen that [AirParrot](http://airparrot.com/) does it, but it's a little slower than the OS X  integrated app.

> Desktop Extension. Add more space to your desktop by creating a virtual monitor and extending your desktop to your TV. (OS X Only)

Comment: Thanks Esteban. I clarified the question to say "is there an option" rather than "is there a way".

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X Mavericks now supports this feature out of the box.